# How to turn quiz from the text type to the image type in android?

Tags: android

These questions of the text type
I want to turn them into questions type of image
in the sense explained
The question I want to be an image, not (5 + 2),(2+15),....
is that possible???
I am Beginning in android

```html
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  dbase = db;
  String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
    + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
    + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT)";
  db.execSQL(sql);
  addQuestion();
  // db.close();
 }
 private void addQuestion() {
  Question q1 = new Question("5+2 = ?", "7", "8", "6", "7");
  this.addQuestion(q1);
  Question q2 = new Question("2+18 = ?", "18", "19", "20", "20");
  this.addQuestion(q2);
  Question q3 = new Question("10-3 = ?", "6", "7", "8", "7");
  this.addQuestion(q3);
  Question q4 = new Question("5+7 = ?", "12", "13", "14", "12");
  this.addQuestion(q4);
  Question q5 = new Question("3-1 = ?", "1", "3", "2", "2");
  this.addQuestion(q5);
  Question q6 = new Question("0+1 = ?", "1", "0", "10", "1");
  this.addQuestion(q6);
  Question q7 = new Question("9-9 = ?", "0", "9", "1", "0");
  this.addQuestion(q7);
  Question q8 = new Question("3+6 = ?", "8", "7", "9", "9");
  this.addQuestion(q8);
  Question q9 = new Question("1+5 = ?", "6", "7", "5", "6");
  this.addQuestion(q9);
  Question q10 = new Question("7-5 = ?", "3", "2", "6", "2");
  this.addQuestion(q10);
  Question q11 = new Question("7-2 = ?", "7", "6", "5", "5");
  this.addQuestion(q11);
  Question q12 = new Question("3+5 = ?", "8", "7", "5", "8");
  this.addQuestion(q12);
  Question q13 = new Question("0+6 = ?", "7", "6", "5", "6");
  this.addQuestion(q13);
  Question q14 = new Question("12-10 = ?", "1", "2", "3", "2");
  this.addQuestion(q14);
  Question q15 = new Question("12+2 = ?", "14", "15", "16", "14");
  this.addQuestion(q15);
  Question q16 = new Question("2-1 = ?", "2", "1", "0", "1");
  this.addQuestion(q16);
  Question q17 = new Question("6-6 = ?", "6", "12", "0", "0");
  this.addQuestion(q17);
  Question q18 = new Question("5-1 = ?", "4", "3", "2", "4");
  this.addQuestion(q18);
  Question q19 = new Question("4+2 = ?", "6", "7", "5", "6");
  this.addQuestion(q19);
  Question q20 = new Question("5+1 = ?", "6", "7", "5", "6");
  this.addQuestion(q20);
  Question q21 = new Question("5-4 = ?", "5", "4", "1", "1");
  this.addQuestion(q21);
  // END
 }
 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
  // Drop older table if existed
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
  // Create tables again
  onCreate(db);
 }
 // Adding new question
 public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
  // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
  values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
  values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
  values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
  values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
  // Inserting Row
  dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
 }
 public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
  List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
  // Select All Query
  String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
  dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
  // looping through all rows and adding to list
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
    Question quest = new Question();
    quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
    quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
    quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
    quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
    quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
    quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
    quesList.add(quest);
   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  // return quest list
  return quesList;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. A couple of them:

**Use a Map**
Keep a Map where the keys is the Question ID in your data base. The values  stored in the map for each key could be the Images Views (loaded as resources for instance)

**Add a field in DB**
Add a field with the relative path of the image and load the corresponding image for every question.

You can store the path as an String in your DB and then recover the image as this:

```
File imgFile = new  File("/path/of/image/image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    // This image view is defined as a resource.... just set the bitmap
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anyImageView);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Comment: How to add image in field ?

Comment: What doesn't work??? you have to adapt the code to load the image from your filesystem and get the correct resource from your configuration. That was an example of how to load an image and show it in a ImageView. As you didn't post your code, I can't do anything else just try to give you an example...

Comment: String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
+ " String, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
+ KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, "+"KEY_IMAGE +  BLOB)";
  db.execSQL(sql);
  addQuestion();
  // db.close();
  File KEY_QUES = new  File("/path/of/image/image.jpg");

  if(KEY_QUES.exists()){

      Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(KEY_QUES.getAbsolutePath());

      ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

Comment: please help me >> what is File("/path/of/image/image.jpg")??

Comment: That is an example of an image path. You're creating a File with that concrete path. For example, your image is stored in this path: "/home/user/images/myImage.jpg", So, you create the File object like this: File f = new File("/home/user/images/myImage.jpg")

Comment: Looking at the code you posted, I can't figure out where are your images stored, if they are directly imported as a resources of your app or if you load them directly from file system. In my example, images would be loaded from file system

Comment: By the way, my suggestion is not to store the image as is in the database, but store just the path of the image in the filesystem. And then you load that image from the file system in your ImageView as I suggested in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage); // the original file yourimage.jpg i added in resources
Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

String yourText = "3+5 = ?";

Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
Paint tPaint = new Paint();
tPaint.setTextSize(35);
tPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
tPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
cs.drawBitmap(src, 0f, 0f, null);
float height = tPaint.measureText("yY");
float width = tPaint.measureText(yourText);
float x_coord = (src.getWidth() - width)/2;
cs.drawText(yourText, x_coord, height+15f, tPaint); // 15f is to put space between top edge and the text, if you want to change it, you can
try {
    dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/ImageAfterAddingText.jpg")));
    // dest is Bitmap, if you want to preview the final image, you can display it on screen also before saving
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code generates image from custom text
Don't forget to add permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```